# How to handle different JSON responce model in Retrofit2

Tags: json, models, retrofit2

Here`s the story - usual login case with Retrofit2. I post login & password and if everything is fine i get complete  class with Call

```
{ 
    "status": 1,
    "payload": {
    "user_id": 123,
    "name": "User123",
    "email": "User123@mail.com",
    "gender": "m",
and so on...}
```

but if user not exist or password not correct i`ll get

```
<Error>
{  
    "status": 2,
    "payload": "",
    "error": [
    {
      "field": "password",
      "message": "Email or Password is incorrect"
    }
 ]}
```

How to handle this situation? I understand that if (!responce.issuccess) - but i need to know what went wrong - user mistyped password or his email is not registered? I tried to get class by

```
if(responce.body.instanceof(UserData){
  //like ok
} else if (responce.bodu.instanceof(Error)){
  //get reason of error
}
```

But this not work.
Classes for UserData and Error created with all rules for POJO.

Comment: it's a security feature not telling the client if the user exist's or not.

Comment: There`s no big security at all, but user have no know what`s the reason for not logging in.